# Can I better use memory in this program?

Tags: java, memory-management

The code below works the way I want it to work. I was just wanting to see if I was using the necessary amount of memory and not too much of it. I want to go into programming as my career so it would be nice to hear from some of the professionals out there.

```
import java.util.*;
public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0, number, guess, yes = 1, no =2, answer;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        number = ((int) (Math.random() * 100));

        System.out.println("Would you like to play the guessing game?");
        System.out.println("Enter " + yes + " for yes, and enter " + no + " for no");
        answer = input.nextInt();

        if(answer == no) {
            return;
        } else {
            while (answer == yes) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the guessing game");
            System.out.println("There has been a number between 1 and 100 picked \n You have five chances to guess the number");
            System.out.print("Please enter your guess >> ");
            guess = input.nextInt();

            while (guess != number) {
                if (guess != number) {
                    counter = ++counter;
                }
                if (counter == 5) {
                    System.out.println("You have used all your guesses");
                    System.out.println("The number was " + number);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                    System.out.println("Enter " + yes + " for yes and " + no + " for no");
                    answer = input.nextInt();
                    counter = -1;
                    if (answer == no)
                    return;
                } else if (guess < number) {
                    System.out.println("You need to guess higher");
                    System.out.println("You have used " + counter + " guess(es)");
                    System.out.println("Please enter your new guess");
                    guess = input.nextInt();
                } else if (guess > number) {
                    System.out.println("You need to guess lower");
                    System.out.println("You have used " + counter + " guess(es)");
                    System.out.println("Please enter your new guess");
                    guess = input.nextInt();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("You win");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again");
                System.out.println("Enter " + yes + " for yes and " + no + " for no");
                answer = input.nextInt();
                if(answer == no)
                    return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about memory optimisation unless you have memory profiled your application and it has found a problem.  Your time is money and often 1 GB of memory is cheaper than an hour of your time, 1 MB is worth a few seconds and 1 KB isn't worth the time it takes you to press one key, and you are not even using 1 KB of objects.

In a much bigger program I suggest you use `jmc` to profile your application, and in particular look at allocation rate and think about how you can decrease it.